# PHP GET request sent by ESP8266 Wifi chip but not received by website

Tags: php, apache, serial-port, at-command, esp8266

I am building a simple website which should update a text file when the host receives data from another device connected to the same network. The device in question is a small weather station which measures temperature. The temperature is sent by the station in a PHP GET command through Wifi from an ESP8266 chip. The signal is received by the home router and redirected to a laptop on the network which is hosting the website.

I am having issues because the ESP8266 chip seems to send the data/PHP GET command correctly. Yet the website never updates itself.

In order to simplify the system for troubleshooting, the weather station is replaced by the laptop. The laptop is connected directly to the ESP8266 chip through a USB-to-Serial(UART) cable. All the AT commands to communicate with the ESP8266 chip are typed in the Arduino IDE Serial Monitor.

**The website**

The website is very simple. Whenever it receives data from the ESP8266 chip, it writes it in a text file.

The website is stored on a laptop whose IP is 192.168.1.2.

```
phodor@UBUNTU:~$ ifconfig    
wlp2s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 18:cf:5e:ee:3f:10  
          inet addr:192.168.1.2  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
```

The website is a php file hosted on an apache2 server. When executed, the php file stores the temperature in file data.txt. The files are stored at /var/www/html.

```
phodor@UBUNTU:~$ ls -la /var/www/html
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root     0 Jul 31 22:41 data.txt
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   127 Jul 31 21:40 index.php
```

Any GET request sent to the PHP file should contain the temperature so the PHP file can store the temperature in data.txt.

```
phodor@UBUNTU:~$ cat /var/www/html/index.php 

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<?php
  $a = $_GET['temp'];
  $dataSaved = file_put_contents("data.txt",$a . "\n",FILE_APPEND);  
  echo "Temperature is " . $a . " oC.";  
?>
</body>
</html>
```

When I type manually the following line in Firefox:

```
http://192.168.1.2/index.php?temp=28
```

The following text gets displayed in the browser & number "28" gets saved in data.txt.

```
Temperature is 28 oC.
```

**The ESP8266 Chip**

As explained above, in the final system the ESP8266 chip will receive serial instructions from a small weather station. But in order to simplify debugging, the chip is now connected to the laptop with a USB-to-Serial (UART) cable. Serial commands are sent to the chip by using the Arduino IDE Serial Monitor. Here are the commands sent.

```
AT

OK
AT+CWLAP
+CWLAP:(3,"MYMODEM",-31,"aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff",1,21)

OK
AT+CWJAP="MYMODEM","mypassword"

WIFI CONNECTED
WIFI GOT IP

OK
AT+CIPSTART="TCP","192.168.1.2",80
CONNECT

OK
AT+CIPSEND=56

OK
> GET /index.php?temp=10 HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: 192.168.1.2\r\n\r\n

busy s...

Recv 56 bytes

SEND OK
CLOSED
```

So at this point, message "Temperature is 10 oC." should appear in the Serial Monitor and the number "10" should get appended to file "data.txt". But nothing happens...

Any suggestions?

**Additional Notes**

1) The PHP and AT code I am using is very similar to what is presented in this post: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q02f4sPghSo   .

2) As was pointed in some comments below, the GET command might be less conventional. POST or PUT might be more appropriate. Yet at the moment I am only trying to understand why the website is not responding to the chip.

Comment: FYI it is poor/unconventional/contra-indicated style to use a GET request to modify the state of the server. You should use POST or PUT.

Comment: Use a protocol sniffer to see what is actually happening on the network, to see what request/response is happening.

Comment: @barny: Thanks for the info above. Any protocol sniffer to suggest? I am not familiar with protocol sniffers.

Comment: https://www.wireshark.org/ is probably your best choice, it has a graphical front-end and is easy to get started with.

Comment: `Recv 56 bytes` - what are they?

Comment: Are you sending actual backslash characters instead of carriage return and newline characters? Either way I don't see how that request is 56 bytes long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I've figure out the problem.

It turns out that the Arduino IDE Serial Monitor does not recognize "\r" and "\n" as special characters and treats them as 4 characters. However, when I type "Enter" (or click on the "Send button") in the Arduino IDE Serial Monitor, it automatically sends a carriage return & a line feed character (two characters more than the string I am trying to send). Therefore, whenever I want to send "\r\n" to Serial via the IDE, i need to do it by pressing Enter. If there is such a "\r\n" in the middle of the string I want to send (as is the case in my example), the string must be cut in two (or more).

I therefore modified this part of my code:

```
AT+CIPSEND=56

OK
> GET /index.php?temp=10 HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: 192.168.1.2\r\n\r\n
```

by this:

```
AT+CIPSEND=33


OK
> GET /index.php?temp=10 HTTP/1.1        (here I press "Enter")
Recv 33 bytes

SEND OK
AT+CIPSEND=21


OK
> Host: 192.168.1.2          (here I press "Enter")
Recv 21 bytes

SEND OK
```

Note that "GET /index.php?temp=10 HTTP/1.1" is 31 characters long. Two characters will be added by the Serial Monitor when I click "Enter". This explains `AT+CIPSEND=33` for sending this line, and not `AT+CIPSEND=31`.

Similarly, "Host: 192.168.1.2" is 19 characters long. When adding 2 characters for carriage-return-and-line-feed, we get 21 characters, so `AT+CIPSEND=21`.

The server then answers with the correct response.

```
+IPD,215:HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sat, 06 Aug 2016 13:39:59 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)
Content-Length: 67
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
Temperature is 10 oC.</body>
</html>
CLOSED
```